# get source html with puppeteer

Tags: dart, puppeteer

I am already using [puppeteer](https://pub.dev/packages/puppeteer) to **scrape** my page, however, I also need the raw html (basically the page-source).

I know I can fetch the raw html, but maybe puppeteer has it saved somewhere.

Does puppeteer save the page source after a goto()?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `goto` method returns a promise which resolves to the main resource response. So you can do something like this:

```
const response = await page.goto(url);
console.log(await response.text());
```

But I would recommend using the `page.content()` method to get the full HTML contents of the page, including the doctype. Read more about [content](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.content).